# Item order in nested Repeaters

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have 2 nested Repeaters, my problem is about the displaying the result. I want it to be displayed like this:

Caption1

```
  Images1
```

Caption2 (should be at new line but not)

```
  Images2
```

Caption3 (should be at new line but not)

```
  Images3
```

But the result is this:

http://s22.postimg.org/v53xrz40h/Capture.jpg

So how can i solve this?

Thanks.

**HTML:**

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptReferansBaslik" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptReferansBaslik_ItemDataBound">

                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <p>
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCaption" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Ref_Baslik") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </p>
                            <asp:Repeater ID="rptCalismalar" runat="server">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <ul id="mb_imagelist" class="mb_imagelist">
                                        <li>
                                            <img src='images/small/<%#Eval("CI_ThumNailURL") %>' alt="image1" data-bgimg='images/big/<%#Eval("CI_ImageURL") %>' /></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>

                        </ItemTemplate>

  </asp:Repeater>
```

**Code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //List<Referanslar> list = Referanslar.GetReferanslarList("");
        rptReferanslar.DataSource = Referanslar.GetReferanslarList("");
        rptReferanslar.DataBind();
        rptReferansBaslik.DataSource = Referanslar.GetReferanslarList("");
        rptReferansBaslik.DataBind();
    }

    protected void rptReferansBaslik_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Repeater rp = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptCalismalar"); 
        int id = int.Parse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Ref_ID").ToString());
        rp.DataSource = CalismalarImages.GetCalismalarImagesList("SELECT * FROM CalismalarImages WHERE CI_CalismaID=" + id);
        rp.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Look at your output html by just doing a View Source in the browser. From there it should be relatively easy to figure out what the problem is...and once you know how to fix it in the static code, translating that change back to the server side is probably straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this case, I think you should use ListView instead of repeater. What you can do is to create a listview "parentListview" and then a listview "childRepeater" like this :

```
//Link mannually OnItemDataBound to ItemBound --
<asp:ListView ID="parentListview" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ItemBound">
          <ItemTemplate>
                ...
                <asp:Repeater ID="childRepeater" runat="server">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                                  ...
                           </ItemTemplate>
                 </asp:Repeater>

          </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

The code should look like this :

```
parentListview.DataSource = Listtournoiterminer;
parentListview.DataBind();
```

And then :

```
protected void ItemBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs args)
{

        Repeater childRepeater = (Repeater)args.Item.FindControl("childRepeater");

        ...

        childRepeater.DataSource = Top3;
        childRepeater.DataBind();

}
```

I hope this helped you !