# How to display nested data correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working in asp.net C# and I am having a hard time figuring out how to approach a problem. I have a database containing information about companies. I want to post this on the website in the following way:

---

**Country Name**

---

(if there is more than one company in the same country it displays 2 sets in one row)

**Company Name**: Label-------------------------------------**Company Name**: Label

**Address**: Label-----------------------------------------------**Address**: Label

---

---

**Country Name**

---

**Company Name**: Label

**Address**: Label

---

etc...

So to solve this I started using:

```
 DataGrid1.DataSource = Database.QueryTable(string.Format("select * from (myTable) group by country"));
 DataGrid1.DataBind();



protected void DataGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e) {

if (e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.AlternatingItem && e.Item.ItemType != ListItemType.Item)
return;

DataRowView drItem   = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
int countryId        = Convert.ToInt32(drItem[Common.Data.Reseller.Constants.countryid]);
Label lblAddress     = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblAddress");
Label lblComanyName  = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblComanyName");
Label lblCountryName = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblCountryName");
DataRow drCountry    = Database.QueryRow(Common.Data.Country.Get.CountryByID(countryId));

DataTable dt = Database.QueryTable(string.Format("select * from (myTable) order by countryid"));

lblCountryName.Text = drCountry[Common.Data.Country.Constants.countryName].ToString(); 
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows) {
  if (Convert.ToInt32(dr[Common.Data.Reseller.Constants.countryid]).Equals(countryId)) {
```

etc...I set out all the information in this "if" statement.

So I am hoping it obvious to someone that this does not get my desired results. After doing a bit of research I am stumped on how to continue. Do I use nested gridViews, or repeaters, or is there something else that I should be considering here. I am just hoping to be pointed in the right direction so that I know what I should be researching.

Comment: One option is to use nested repeaters.  Get the list of countries and bind it to the outer repeater, then on the ItemDataBound event grab the companies for a given country and bind that to the inner repeater.

Comment: Jacob, thank you for the direction. I will work on using your suggestion. I really appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use nested ListView for that. I had the same problem, I was trying to do something like that :

[image]

The two box is event, and the lines inside is the people who participate. I know it is not on the same line, but you should be able to do it. There's a question I already answered about that, [Nested listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379207/item-order-in-nested-repeaters/16443710#16443710).

Hope this will help you, vinc.

Comment: Great, I will have a look, and try it out. Thanks for the suggestion!